# sklearn classifier - predict_proba threshold that maximizes auc

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, roc

I have a three-class classification problem. I train the classifier and then plot the ROC for the different classes.

[image]

I need to get the threshold for each class which maximizes the TPR and minimizes the FPR. In Matlab, this is returned. Is there a way to retrieve this in python / sklearn?

Thanks.

Comment: the `roc_curve` returns tpr, fpr and thresholds. You can not simultaneously maximize TPF and minimize FPR in a proper manner. I Do you just intend to find the point on the curve closest to the upper left of the diagram point (0, 1)?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I have the TPR, FPR and the array of thresholds from the function outputs. Yes, I need the threshold for the point on the curve which is closest to top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my idea looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.linalg.norm(
    (np.array([[0, 1]]) -np.stack([fpr, tpr], axis=1)), 
    axis=1).argmax()
max_thresh = thresholds[idx]
```

what is done here: stack the FPR and TPR together as a 2D-vector. subtract the upper left corner of each row of the vector and take the norm. This computes the distance. Take the argmax to know in which row the maximum value appears. Finally, return the threshold at that index

Comment: with np.array([[0, 1]], I was getting the top right corner, I used np.array([[1, 0]] to get the top left corner. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, but if FPR is the x axis and TPR the y-axis -> then (0,1) should be the correct point. Nevertheless, if it works out for you, I'm happy as well

Comment: @DreX if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents)